# SpEL parsing parameters with "Collectors.toList()" in stream won't work as expressionString?

Tags: spring, java-8, spring-el

This will work

```
parser.parseExpression("#configList.stream().toArray()").getValue(context)
```

but the following won't

```
parser.parseExpression("#configList.stream().map(o -> o.ruleId).collect(Collectors.toList())").getValue(context)
```

F.Y.I the context is constructed as follows:

```
        Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
        Method method = ((MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature()).getMethod();
        String[] params = discoverer.getParameterNames(method);
        EvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
        for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            context.setVariable(params[i], args[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although Java can be used in SPeL expressions, SPeL itself is a separate language and does not *fully* support the Java language. From the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-intro):

> SpEL is based on a *technology agnostic* API allowing other expression language implementations to be integrated should the need arise.

To perform filtering and mapping operations on a List in a SPeL expression, use [collection selection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-collection-selection) and [collection projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-collection-projection) respectively:

**Collection selection example**

```java
// Java:
configList.stream().filter(o -> o.getRuleId() > 2).collect(Collectors.toList())

// SPeL (notice the question mark) :
"#configList.?[ruleId>2]"
```

**Collection projection example**

```java
// Java:
configList.stream().map(o -> o.getRuleId()).collect(Collectors.toList())

// SPeL (notice the exclamation mark) :
"#configList.![ruleId]"
```

I have set up a small example to demonstrate it:

```java
public class So64738543ExpressionTest {
    public static class RuleItem {
        private int ruleId;

        public RuleItem(int ruleId) {
            this.ruleId = ruleId;
        }

        public int getRuleId() {
            return ruleId;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void collectionProjection() {
        List<RuleItem> ruleItems = Arrays.asList(new RuleItem(1), new RuleItem(2), new RuleItem(3));
        EvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext(ruleItems);

        Expression expression = new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("#root.![ruleId]");
        Assert.assertEquals(Arrays.asList(1,2,3), expression.getValue(context));
    }
}
```

[edit]

Furthermore, if a SPeL expression becomes increasingly complex, I **highly** recommend to move the expression to a static method and invoke it using a [`T operator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-types). Don't forget to include the fully qualified package name when referring to the static method.